# jQuery Mobile - Side by side numeric input with a slider

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile.  I am attempting to allow the user to change a slider value in two ways.  A number, or a percentage.  For example, let's say that the total of a metric is $224.  So 50% is $112.  Well, I want the user to be able to specify $100 manually, OR specify 50% manually.

With this said, I placed a numeric text box and a slider next to each other.  The numeric text box appears larger and different from the slider's text box.  One thing to note - I have removed the up/down buttons via CSS.

Try as I might, I cannot get these to display the same way.  Does anyone know what classes are needed for this?  Changes done on pageinit()?

[image: Slider issue]

Comment: Use `ui-grid` to put them side by side and for the text box, you need to adjust the style of its parent. `$('[type=number]').closest('div').css('height', '30px');`. Try it.

Comment: example http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2gfVa/

Comment: Thank you! I played around with the CSS until I got the borders to match as well. Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I'm glad I've been of help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put elements side by side, use `ui-grid` layout. For two items, add class `ui-grid-a` to a div. Then wrap first with div with class `ui-block-a` and the other one class `ui-block-b`.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2gfVa/)**

```
<form>
 <div class="ui-grid-a">
  <div class="ui-block-a">
   <label for="numbers"></label>
   <input type="number" name="numbers" id="number" />
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-b">
   <label for="slider-6" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Slider:</label>
   <input type="range" name="slider-6" id="slider-6" min="0" max="100" value="50" />
  </div>
 </div>
```

Optional - Override width of child divs.

```
.ui-block-a { width: 30% !important; padding-right: 10px !important }
.ui-block-b { width: 70% !important }
```

For input, you need to adjust input's parent div's height by either jQuery or CSS.

**Note:** Slider has `type=number` attribute as well, therefore, you need to override the input box only which has class `ui-input-text`.

CSS

```
div.ui-input-text { height: 28px !important }
```

jQuery

```
$('[type=number]').closest('div.ui-input-text').css('height', '28px');
```